# Cofoundry CMS send email to new users

Tags: email, content-management-system, cofoundry

I am facing an issue with the Cofoundry .NET core CMS.
Basically, I have installed is successfully and able to login via admin panel.

Now issue is, when I am adding more users in the CMS, it does not send emails to newly added user. However, in the admin panel users added successfully.

Please note: I have configured SendGrid plugin and that is working ok, tried by sending custom email.

Not sure, if further settings are required to get the emails working for new users add.
Please let me know If anyone faced the same issue earlier.

Regards,
Vivek Kumar

Comment: We'll need to see your code to help.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for replying. This is the default installation of cofoundry and just added sendgrid plugin for emails as given in cofoundry docs. I have followed this to install cofoundry https://www.cofoundry.org/docs/getting-started/installing

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to ensure Cofoundry is configured to send the mail. The setting you want is `Cofoundry:Mail:SendMode`, the default value is `LocalDrop` to prevent you accidently sending debug emails to people, so by default the email will end up in your App_Data directory. You should set this to Send. So your config would look like this:

```json
{
    "Cofoundry": {
        "Mail": {
            "SendMode": "Send",
            "DefaultFromAddress": "auto@example.com"
        },
    },
}
```

Mail config settings are covered in the [config settings docs](https://www.cofoundry.org/docs/references/common-config-settings#mailsettings)

If this is not set up then your email will be placed in the mail drop directory, which defaults to "~/App_Data/Emails", so check there to see if the mail behaving in debug mode.

If there was an error sending the mail, then you would see an error prompt in the admin panel, so perhaps next you should check your SendGrid logs to see if the email is being passed through their service - perhaps it is being blocked or sent to spam?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have already added that setting as suggested in their docs for email configuration but still emails are not going through.

Comment: I found the issue and it was due to mail settings was define under the plugin section, rather it has to be outside of it. Anyways, thanks for your and support, appreciate it .